# Can't figure out how to use webpack's require.context()

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, webpack

I have an AngularJS with webpack project, and I want to import all the .js files in my project to webpack without adding the path of each file individually, so on the webpack docs I found this require.context() and it looked straight forward, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
webpackEmptyContext(req) {
    var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
    e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
    throw e;
}
```

This is how the function is declared, I used the same example that they gave on the docs:

```
function importAll(r) {
  console.log(r)
  r.keys().forEach(r);
}

importAll(require.context('./src', true, /\.js$/));
```

I'm using node 10 and webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

The path argument in the `require.context` call is relative to your file that declared the function. If the file that calls `require.context` is deep in your `src` directory, you may try locating your `src` directory by something like `../../../../src` and put this string into the argument.